# Show and focus TextBox in DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, textbox, focus, visibility

I have searched high and low, but I can't figure this one out.  I am building a `ListBox` that has editable items.  I have a `DataTemplate` for the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` that contains (among other things) a `TextBlock` and a `TextBox`.  The `TextBlock` is always visible, and the `TextBox` is only visible after the user double-clicks on the `TextBlock`.  When the user clicks another item in the list, the `TextBox` hides again to show the `TextBlock`.  All of this works great.  See my code:

XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:GoalCollection x:Key="goals"/>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="GoalItemTemplate" DataType="local:Goal">
      <Grid>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                    MouseLeftButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
         <TextBox Name="EntryBox"
                  Text="{Binding Title}"
                  Visibility="Hidden"
                  BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                  Padding="-2,0,0,0"
                  Panel.ZIndex="1"
                  Margin="-2,0,0,0"/>
      </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ListBox Name="GoalsList"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource goals}}"
      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GoalItemTemplate}"
      SelectionChanged="GoalsList_SelectionChanged" />
</Grid>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    GoalCollection goals;
    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    private childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj)
    where childItem : DependencyObject { ... }

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
       base.OnInitialized(e);
       goals = (GoalCollection)Resources["goals"];
    }

    private void TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, 
                                               MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.ClickCount == 2)
       {
          TextBlock tblk = sender as TextBlock;
          if (tblk == null) 
             return;
          TextBox tbx = ((Grid)tblk.Parent).FindName("EntryBox") as TextBox;
          if (tbx == null) 
             return;
          tbx.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
          Keyboard.Focus(tbx);
       }
    }

    private void GoalsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, 
                                            SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       ListBoxItem lbi;
       ContentPresenter cp;
       DataTemplate dt;
       TextBox tbx;

       foreach (Goal item in e.RemovedItems)
       {
          lbi = (ListBoxItem)GoalsList.ItemContainerGenerator.
                                       ContainerFromItem(item);
          cp = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(lbi);
          dt = cp.ContentTemplate;
          tbx = (TextBox)dt.FindName("EntryBox", cp);
          if (tbx == null) 
             continue;
          tbx.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
       }
    }
 }
```

The problem that I'm having is that the `TextBox` immediately shifts focus back to the host `ListBoxItem` after the double-click.  An additional (third) click is required to focus on the TextBox.

Tracing through this, I have found that the `TextBox` does indeed receive focus.  But then it immediately loses it (try adding a handler for the `TextBox.LostKeyboardFocus` event and step through and out of the `TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonDown()' method).  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My *guess* is that the click event is bubbling up to the ListBox and it's handling it by selecting the item.

Try adding this to your Click event handler (after `Keyboard.Focus(tbx);`)

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: You, sir, are a genius!  I keep forgetting about that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to give focus to a child element, try the FocusManager.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate" DataType="ListBoxItem">
   <Grid>
      <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                 FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=tbText}">
         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Completed}" Margin="5" />
         <Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DeleteButtonTemplate}" 
                 Margin="5" Click="btnDeleteItem_Click" />
         <TextBox Name="tbText" 
                  Text="{Binding Path=Text}" 
                  Width="200" 
                  TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                  AcceptsReturn="True" 
                  Margin="5" 
                  Focusable="True"/>
         <DatePicker Text="{Binding Path=Date}" Margin="5"/>
      </WrapPanel>
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```